# Overhead/risks of passing messages to nil

Tags: objective-c, null

I wonder if there are any risks about relying on the fact that passing messages to nil objects does nothing in objective C.

In my code I have a lot of weak references to UIKit and other objects that could be niled anytime. Since I came from C++ and languages where referencing NULL is the quickest way how to crash the program I always tend to be cautious and write defensive codelike this:

```
if (view)
   [view removeFromSuperview];
```

Is there actually any point of checking if the view is not nil before passing messages to it? I know that in this case (removing a subview from superview it is safe), but are there any situation where this could be a problem?

How about performance implications? Is the passing a message to nil actually free and really does nothing? What if I let's say do it thousand times in a loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method calls in Objective-C are handled by translating them into calls to `objc_msgSend()`, which first checks to see if the receiver is `nil`, and then it translates this to a method call to a special "nil" object.  (See blog post: [Nil](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/nil.html)).  The method call is designed to return 0 for all types.  See [Working with Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22):

> **Note:** If you expect a return value from a message sent to `nil`, the return value will be `nil` for object return types, `0` for numeric types, and `NO` for `BOOL` types. Returned structures have all members initialized to zero.

So it is **always safe**.  Unless you support legacy systems...

### For legacy coders...

It used to be that `objc_msgSend()` would only return 0 in the usual register for scalar function returns.  The ABI on PowerPC specified that `r3` would be used for integer and pointer returns, and sometimes for the first field of a structure if the structure was packed into registers.  However, different registers were used for floating point numbers, and these would not get initialized, and structs would not always get initialized.

This was an extremely rare problem, but it has been solved anyway.

Comment: Excellent warning about returned structs. And any opportunity to link to the fish is an opportunity well taken.

Comment: Note that in ARC, the compiler will handle all of those tricky cases for you, including zeroing out structs

Comment: It appears to be true but I am concerned that there is no citation supporting this, or that it may be a quirk of the ABI.

Comment: ARC only promises to initialize objects (See Transitioning to ARC Release Notes:Stack Variables Are Initialized with nil). You would think it'd be in the ObjC ARC documentation for Clang, but I can't find it there. But it's possible that structs are being treated as objects (since they look about the same). Stack ints definitely are not initialized (run it in Release and you'll see).

Comment: Double checked. Structs are not initialized. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/8202731

Comment: I tried with -O0, -O1, and -O2, and I tried calling functions to scribble on the stack and scribble in registers, but I always got zeroes.  Haven't looked at assembly, though.

Comment: I get zeros very often with CGPoint, and sometimes with other float types (but not always). But it's very reliably garbage for ints. Interesting note: Clang does not complain about an uninitialized variable if you pass an uninitialized struct (which made me think for a moment it really was treating it as an object).

Comment: "If your method returns float or double, the result may be garbage." See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22 "If you expect a return value from a message sent to nil, the return value will be nil for object return types, 0 for numeric types, and NO for BOOL types. Returned structures have all members initialized to zero." `float` and `double` are numeric types, so the return should be 0. Though the last sentence seems to be wrong.

Comment: @newacct: I am entirely baffled why you didn't turn that into an answer.  That's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: it wasn't directly related to "overhead/risks" of passing messages to nil

Comment: It's been safe since at least 2012: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html (Greg would know.)

Answer (score 3):

Passing messages to `nil` is quite normal and expected in Objective-C. You generally should not protect against it. Keep in mind, however, that passing `nil` to some methods (`addObject:` for instance) will crash, so you do need to think about when a variable can and cannot be `nil`.

`objc_msgSend` is highly optimized to handle messaging nil. [Greg Parker has done a nice job laying out the different versions that have existed since 10.0.](http://sealiesoftware.com/msg/) The very first assembly instruction in `objc_msgSend` is a test for `nil` and an immediate return.

---

EDIT:

See Dietrich Epp's answer regarding how this works for non-object returns. He makes a great point that you do need to be careful in that case.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple Documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

> A nil value is the safest way to initialize an object pointer if you don’t have another value to use, because it’s perfectly acceptable in Objective-C to send a message to nil. If you do send a message to nil, obviously nothing happens.

This means that You can send what you want to nil objects and nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

Greg Parker, Apple's runtime guy, wrote a blog post on the subject here: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html

I consider this even more definitive than an Apple link would be, since it's also dated.

Messaging nil will return 0 for any integer up to 64-bits, floating point up to long double, pointer, struct or _Complex. Note that calling `objc_msgSend_stret` directly does not have the same behaviour in all cases.

Since the runtime needs to look up the class to dispatch the message correctly, I imagine it discovers the instance is nil fairly early.